# How to aggregate using $lookup when foreignField value is not in localField

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to aggregate data from 2 collections

When there is a localField value that is not in foreign field, the the aggregated results still contains the localField value and the data that was supposed to be matched to it is null. But when there is a foreignField value that is not in the localField, that line of data is not in the final results.

In my case, the local and foreign fields are their respective keys.
Here are some pictures to clarify what I mean.

values saved in 2 collections (have been passed into mongoDB as JSON): [picture of excel files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64wDD.jpg)

collection A example:

```
  /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dad17507c3ad142d46d212f"),
    "joina_key" : "key",
    "joina_value1" : "value 1",
    "joina_value2" : "value 2",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dad17507c3ad142d46d2133"),
    "joina_key" : "D1",
    "joina_value1" : "4",
    "joina_value2" : "8",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dad17507c3ad142d46d2131"),
    "joina_key" : "B1",
    "joina_value1" : "2",
    "joina_value2" : "4",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dad17507c3ad142d46d2132"),
    "joina_key" : "C1",
    "joina_value1" : "3",
    "joina_value2" : "6",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dad17507c3ad142d46d2130"),
    "joina_key" : "A1",
    "joina_value1" : "1",
    "joina_value2" : "2",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

collection B example:

```
  /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dad17d532987d08a8e3e009"),
    "joinb_key" : "key",
    "joinb_mult1" : "multiple 1",
    "joinb_mult2" : "multiple 2",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dad17d532987d08a8e3e00a"),
    "joinb_key" : "A1",
    "joinb_mult1" : "10",
    "joinb_mult2" : "20",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dad17d532987d08a8e3e00b"),
    "joinb_key" : "B1",
    "joinb_mult1" : "10",
    "joinb_mult2" : "20",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dad17d532987d08a8e3e00c"),
    "joinb_key" : "C1",
    "joinb_mult1" : "10",
    "joinb_mult2" : "20",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dad17d532987d08a8e3e00d"),
    "joinb_key" : "D2",
    "joinb_mult1" : "10",
    "joinb_mult2" : "20",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Output I have and output I'm  trying to achieve: [picture of outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXMkP.jpg)

I was wondering if anyone knows how to achieve this.

I'm quite new to this, if I left anything out please do tell me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Query

```
db.tester.aggregate([
    {$lookup: {
        from: 'demo',
        pipeline: [
            { $sort: { joinb_key: 1}},
        ],
        as: 'pointValue',
    }},
    { "$addFields": {
        "pointValue": 
          {
              "$filter": {
                      "input": "$pointValue",
                      "as": "sn",
                      "cond": {
                        "$and": [
                          { "$eq": [ "$$sn.joinb_key", "$joina_key" ] },
                     ]
              }
          }
       } 

    }},
   {
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$pointValue", 0 ] }, "$$ROOT" ] } }
    },
    { $project: { joina_key :1,joina_value1:1, joina_value2:1, joinb_mult1:1,joinb_mult2:1,m1_v1: { $multiply: [ "$joinb_mult1", "$joina_value1" ] },m2_v2: { $multiply: [ "$joinb_mult2", "$joina_value2" ] } } }

])
```

Comment: Please check again query if any problem tell me

Comment: im not sure if 'key' refers to a_key or b_key

Comment: it only returns _id , m1_v1 and m2_v2. The v1,v2,m1,m2 are missing. Also m1_v1 and m2_v2 values are null

Comment: Please share collection a and b and with what are you want collection? share by json editor (https://jsoneditoronline.org/)

Comment: mult_1, mult_2 are missing. m1_v1 and m2_v2 still null. And the D2 object from collection B doesn't appear

Comment: can you result print in json editor with you want result in json editor

Comment: result now:
https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=d34f4cb6cd384c58abea7fc61a93b08a

result I want:
https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=956d5e962a194ca49415696432304188

Comment: Please multiple and value must be integer. Not string

Comment: Please tell which collection have more than other collection ?

Comment: always have more than data collection a or collection b ?

Comment: I'm not very sure what your question is, I have the wanted output in the picture above

Comment: thanx for telling me but you have only integer value for multiply